# All estimators should implement fit and transform

Tags: python

I am new to machine learning. pls help me with this error. below is my code:
I am trying to create a custom class catEncoder() to transform my categorical variables.

```
class DFSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, Attr):
        self.Attr = Attr
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        print(self.Attr)
        return X[self.Attr].values

class catEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        #Some-codes to encode variables
        return X.values

numPipeline = [
                ('selector', DFSelector(numAttr)),
                ('imputer', Imputer(strategy = 'median'))
]
catPipeline = [
                ('selector', DFSelector(catAttr)),
                ('encoder', catEncoder())
]
fullPipe = FeatureUnion(transformer_list = [
                                                ('nPipe', numPipeline),
                                                ('cPipe', catPipeline)
])
Xtrain_ready = fullPipe.fit_transform(Xtrain)
```

I get this following error

```
TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform. '[('selector', DFSelector(Attr=array(['SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare'], dtype=object))), ('imputer', Imputer(axis=0, copy=True, missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', verbose=0))]' (type <class 'list'>) doesn't
```

Comment: BTW, did the answer below help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, the issue seems to be that `FeatureUnion` expects a list of tuples of the form (string, transformer), where transformer is a transformer object. However, in your case it looks like you are passing tuples of the form (string, [multiple transformers]). My suggestion, without having a full view of your ML logic, is to try and split out those list of transformers into individual transformers and pass those to `FeatureUnion`.